# Minor bug: Croatian keyboard layout's ] combo (AltGr+G) results in Insert Image dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, editor

As every programmer, I ] need my ][ square ] brackets.

But at the moment, I have to switch to US layout in order to type them on StackOverflow. Since Croatia is not a big country, it's not all that important... except Hungarian layout also has square brackets in same place: -[- AltGr+F and -]- AltGr+G.

Apparently the underlying software thinks I'm holding Ctrl when I'm in fact holding AltGr... which is not the same :-)

PS StackOverflow is not the only one, this is a rare, but sufficiently common problem: Code::Blocks is mapping AltGr+F as one of its shortcuts

Comment: You can post this on meta.stackoverflow.com - it'll get a better response there (discussion about the sites in general) :)

Comment: ...and look at me, thinking I was on a different site :P

Apologies!

Comment: Yes, it is a common problem with SO, and on many US origin sites. It is a trivial fix as the devs need only to disable shortcut assignments on the editor. But it won't happen. You'll get further if you write a plugin for your browser which hot-fixes the SO editor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Alt Gr + Q giving me Quote formatting instead of the @ sign?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-is-alt-gr-q-giving-me-quote-formatting-instead-of-the-sign)

Answer (score 4):

Same with Hungarian layout. You could use your browser's developer tools to find the hotkey assignment code and manually unassign the handler, but you have to repeat it on every page.

I suggest adding buttons for the [{ characters or create a browser plugin for that. I heard FF does not suffer this issue, but for those who use IE or Chrome on Windows is annoying.

My approach is to open Notepad and type in these characters. Then I copy-paste. (However, when I post a longer code, I already use some other external text editor to replace my tab characters to four spaces.)

(PS: i18n, I wish I had participated in the beta.)

Comment: Actually, this problem appears with Firefox 3.5 on Windows, and I'm not sure about OTHER browsers, but it's probably the same...

Comment: Thanks, haven't tested it with FF3.5, maybe I confused this info from a Linux user's comment I saw some weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the same for altGr+B which is the '{' character on the Hungarian keyboard layout. It is the hotkey for the strong-text.
Same for the AltGr+Y which is the >. It is the hotkey for the 'redo' command.