# Why can't I type characters { > ] into questions and answers?

Tags: bug, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-glyphs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Minor bug: Croatian keyboard layout’s ] combo (AltGr+G) results in Insert Image dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/minor-bug-croatian-keyboard-layouts-combo-altgrg-results-in-insert-image-d)
>   [WMD editor bug: German keyboard layout - “@” creates blockquote section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section)

Hello Everyone,

This is my first question on Meta Stackoverflow.
The issue is pretty simple: I can't type starting braces (`{`), ending angle brackets (`>`) and ending square brackets (`]`) into SO questions or answers.

On typing `{`, the `**strong text**` text appears.
On typing `>`, nothing happens.
On typing `]`, the "insert image" dialog appears.

I suspect that my keyboard layout is responsible. I'm typing with the standard Hungarian keyboard layout and all those characters are accessible with `AltGr` key combinations.

`{` = `AltGr` + `B`
`>` = `AltGr` + `Y`
`]` = `AltGr` + `G`

I think that the site may define keyboard combos for users with English keyboards, which conflicts with my keyboard layout. A possible way to fix this would be to be able to present users with an option to disable these.

So far, the only way I could input those characters was to type them elsewhere and then copy-paste (or swith to other layouts), but this is very inconvenient.

I use Firefox 3.6, but the issue may be present in other browsers as well.
If anyone could recommend any usable workaround, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This might be related to
[this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/minor-bug-croatian-keyboard-layouts-combo-altgrg-results-in-insert-image-d) and [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/wmd-editor-bug-german-keyboard-layout-creates-blockquote-section).

Comment: potential fix is here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19330/problem-with-the-closing-brace/48625#48625

Comment: Thank you very much, but there is no fix, just some thoughts about it.