# Add increase/decrease tab indent buttons to the editor toolbar

Tags: feature-request, editor, tabs

These should work by adding spaces or removing spaces from the beginning of the current line or every line between the start and end of a text selection (inclusive).

(edited this question to supplement [Improvements to editor for formatting source code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/the-editor-possible-improvements))

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/the-editor-possible-improvements

Comment: Too true, but my FR included something additional.  Removed dupe feature request.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't cancel my close vote, but no longer a dupe.

Comment: I'm not against this idea, but I wonder how many people would then think they could indent paragraphs without applying the formatting as code. (Or: be wondered why indented text is formatted as code.)

Comment: I fully support this. Please please please implement it.

Comment: @StephanKristyn Well, this was asked seven years ago, so I don't think there's much chance of that.  You can sort of do this, however, by selecting the chunk of text you want to fix and hitting ctrl-k.  That will either indent it, or if it is indented more than four spaces, move it back.  It's useful for fixing code that's over-indented.

Comment: Related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174966/232804

Answer (score 19):

Yes please on the Tab doing actual spaces instead of taking you out of the box.

**Edit:** This applied to his original question about allowing Tab to work right in the editing textbox.  But indent/dedent buttons would go a long way towards making code formatting user-friendly.

Comment: I would be fine with Tab only modifying indentation when there is a selection, otherwise Tab would enter/leave the text field. Though I would very much like to be able to choose the indent (3 vs. 4 spaces).

Answer (score 14):

**Edit:** Indentation buttons are now [available as a user-script on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2440/increase-decrease-indentation-buttons-for-the-editor).

[image: Extension Screenshot]

---

I [maded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lolspeak#Noun)  my own buttons now. Currently they reside in my bookmarks toolbar:

[image: Buttons]

And they link somewhere nice, the left one for example:

> javascript:var%20tb%20=%20document.getElementById("wmd-input");...

In Firefox and Chrome (the only ones I tested) you can just bookmark scripts, and they nicely convert all the whitespace. Here are the full scripts, nothing special really:

```js
//Indentation Up
var tb = document.getElementById("wmd-input");
var text = tb.value.substring(tb.selectionStart, tb.selectionEnd);
var lines = text.split("\n");
var shift = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    lines[i] = "    " + lines[i];
    shift += 4;
}
replaceSelection(tb, lines.join("\n"));
void (0);

function replaceSelection(textbox, text)
{
    var selectionStart = textbox.selectionStart;
    textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, textbox.selectionStart) + text + textbox.value.substring(textbox.selectionEnd);
    textbox.selectionStart = selectionStart;
    textbox.selectionEnd = selectionStart + text.length;
}
```

```js
//Indentation Down
var tb = document.getElementById("wmd-input");
var text = tb.value.substring(tb.selectionStart, tb.selectionEnd);
var lines = text.split("\n");
var shift = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].substring(0, 4) == "    ")
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(4);
        shift += 4;
    }
    if (lines[i].charCodeAt(0) == 9)
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(1);
        shift++;
    }
}
replaceSelection(tb, lines.join("\n"));
void (0);

function replaceSelection(textbox, text)
{
    var selectionStart = textbox.selectionStart;
    textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, textbox.selectionStart) + text + textbox.value.substring(textbox.selectionEnd);
    textbox.selectionStart = selectionStart;
    textbox.selectionEnd = selectionStart + text.length;
}
```

Note that the preview will not update after the script has been executed. Some calls which would do that could be included I suppose.

(*I am aware that the code is redundant, I just did it this way for simplicity.*)

Comment: Drop that puppy on [stackapps](http://stackapps.com/) and see if you can get some help with it.

Comment: Good idea. Yesterday i wrote a greasemokey script which adds buttons & keyboard shortcuts to the editor, might do some polishing before posting it though.

Comment: @Won't: Submitted it [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/2440/increase-decrease-indentation-buttons-for-the-editor), also added the link to the answer.

Comment: I'd make the favicons the arrows if possible, and make the name blank.

Answer (score 3):

Select a block, or put your cursor on a new line, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> - it'll automatically indent as needed for a code block.

Comment: Actually, that behavior isn't what I'm looking for.  It also behaves weirdly when selecting lines that are already tabified.

Comment: Ctrl+K doesn't work properly on list items. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown

Comment: That's a shame. :-(

Comment: It works for code blocks, though, and if you need to indent a bunch of code that's already indented you can just a dummy character in position one somewhere for long enough to do your insert.

Comment: You should probably update this to note that you can use Ctrl+K to remove indents one stage at a time [as demonstrated here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83173/possible-to-get-add-remove-tabs-button-in-the-question-textbox/83174#83174). Or you could just merge that question into this one... your choice. ♪

Answer (score 0):

What if it looked like this:

[image]

to address concerns like this:

> I'm not against this idea, but I wonder how many people would then think they could indent paragraphs without applying the formatting as code. (Or: be wondered why indented text is formatted as code.) –  Arjan Jul 22 '14 at 22:58

Comment: Please don't reply to comments by adding answers.  That's not how things work here.

Comment: @Won't this answer isn't a reply.  It's an answer.  The comment happens to focus the question on a particular issue that this answer addresses.  I'm not looking to have a discussion so see no need to respond.  If you must comment please comment on the merits of the idea.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Didn't we have a discussion about this previously? You must have deleted your answer and reposted (for some reason). As I stated back then, your answer doesn't explain anything, and an answer which expects others to "work it out for themselves" as you stated last time is not a good answer. Remove the comment from your answer as it is confusing, and just write what your answer is about "*I've made an image with a mock up of what my idea would look like. It should resolve confusions such as...*"