# Make WMD (Wiki Mark Down) convert tabs to spaces

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editor, tabs

Is there any chance the WMD editor could convert pasted tabs (e.g. in sample code etc.) to a fixed number of spaces (e.g. 4) so that the display in the question/answer pane would be easier to read and manage??

I find it very frustrating that tabs aren't visible, and the way the code snippet looks in the WMD editing control and the preview of the results can be quite different indeed.

Comment: What is WMD? ...

Comment: Wiki Mark Down (the "simplified", HTML-like syntax that the editor for  all StackExchange sites uses) - or sometimes also "Wysiwyg Markdown" (although "wysiwyg" seems a bit far fetched ...)

Comment: Note that [this affects languages that actually *need* tabs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143632/tabs-converted-to-spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar/8149#8149) (not precisely the same, but close).