# Add feature to WMD for re-aligning code blocks

Tags: feature-request, editor, code-formatting

Quite often I see code formatted like this in questions:

```
   foo
   bar
   hello
```

If the code consists of sufficiently long lines, it ends up looking like this:

```
                                                                 foobasdsdlfkasdlfksdfoobasdsdlfkasdlfksd
```

It'd be nice if there was a way (an icon to click or a magic keyboard incantation perhaps) to correct those two code blocks to:

```
foo
bar
hello
```

and

```
foobasdsdlfkasdlfksdfoobasdsdlfkasdlfksd
```

respectively.

Presumably this could work by looking at the lowest number of spaces `x` in the selected block, and then reducing the number of initial spaces on each line by `x-4`.

Obviously, there are a small minority of languages where spaces are meaningful that this might change the meaning of, but in most cases I think this would be useful.

I'm aware that I can cut and paste the code into my editor of choice to do this, but it'd be nice if there was some built-in way to do this.

Comment: This is similar (though IMHO) different to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar/8149#8149

Answer (score 1):

There's two big issues with code formatting that leads to side-scrollitis:

1. excessive intendation
2. excessively long lines

#1 can be solved by removing excessive indentation or by converting 8-space tabs to 4 spaces.
#2 can be solved by inserting more line breaks, e.g. turning

```
MyFunction(reallyreallylongarg1, reallyreallylongarg2, reallyreallylongarg3, reallyreallylongarg4, reallyreallylongarg5, reallyreallylongarg6);
```

to:

```
MyFunction(reallyreallylongarg1, reallyreallylongarg2,
    reallyreallylongarg3, reallyreallylongarg4,
    reallyreallylongarg5, reallyreallylongarg6);
```

#1 could possibly be done programmatically by the site, but #2 depends on the syntax of the language and is best done by a human who can decide the best reformatting based on context. But we've got lots of users with editing privileges; does this really need to be addressed programmatically?

*tl;dr:* This is what 2000+ reputation users are for! If you see badly formatted code, step in and clean it up! All hail the Junior Janitor!

Comment: Yes there are lots of users with editing privileges (on SO I'm one of them), and I for one want to fix code that's hard to read - a good deal of which fits into #1, and is tedious to fix by hand. A programmatic fix would make it easier to be a good SO citizen, that's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ctrl+K repeatedly to delete all except the last `N % 4` spaces.

Comment: Not in the version of WMD that Meta is currently using - is that the latest one?

Comment: @Dominic: It Works-For-Me[tm] on SO and here. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Ah - I see what it does. Doesn't quite do what I want, because it doesn't end up as just 4 spaces - as you point out, so I'd still have to edit each line.

Comment: @Dominic: after looking at the WMD source, I came around to see that one to three spaces in front of the source are acceptable :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's open source! You can add that feature yourself!

http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/

Comment: I wish I could, but I'm nowhere near smart enough to figure out what's going on in that JavaScript (http://github.com/cky/wmd/blob/master/wmd-base.js).

Comment: @Dominic: The doCode function is at github.com/derobins/wmd/blob/master/wmd.js line #2106