# remove common whitespace in front of sourcecode blocks

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, editor, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add feature to WMD for re-aligning code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35577/add-feature-to-wmd-for-re-aligning-code-blocks)

People seem to be prone to just paste code from their IDE into stackoverflow, often with reams of whitespace on the left-hand side. This unnecessarily wastes space and often also cuts lines on the right side.

Repairing that manually is almost as annoying as the breakage itself.

> Example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2178418/revisions

Proposal: after detecting a code-block, remove `(smallest number of leading spaces) - 4` spaces from every line.

Comment: That wouldn't work if it is a code block inside of a list item.

Comment: @brad: replace `4` with `$current_wmd_syntax_indent` when reading my proposal. The point would be not to render unneeded left-hand-side whitespace, regardless of positioning.

Comment: oh, darn. this is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35577/add-feature-to-wmd-for-re-aligning-code-blocks and Jeff's answer was "It's open source!"

Comment: Testing revealed that using ^K repeatedly on the block removes all whitespace, except for the last (indent mod 4) spaces.

Comment: The doCode function is at http://github.com/derobins/wmd/blob/master/wmd.js line #2106

Answer (score 1):

Even giving us a button to strip that amount of spaces would be good.  It's a pain to do it manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

If your code example is too long that it's a pain to do manually, consider shortening the code example.

Alternately, put it in a code editor, highlight it, press `shift` - `tab` a couple times, then copy and paste.