# Way to indent/outdent in the editor

Tags: feature-request, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add increase/decrease tab indent buttons to the editor toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar)

Currently hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> moves the focus out of the editor. This is regular behavior for textboxes/textareas, I get that.

However, it becomes a pain while typing in code as tab is used for indenting in most IDEs.

If there was a shortcut to indent/outdent the code, that'd be great!

Can this be supported in anyway?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: [What do upvotes and downvotes mean on Meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)