# Add the ability to tab a block of text in or out in Markdown

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add increase/decrease tab indent buttons to the editor toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar)

I would like the ability to *indent a selected block of text* in Markdown by four spaces, by pushing a button.

This would allow me to change a block of code from

```
public void foo()
{
bar();
baz();
}
```

to look like this:

```
public void foo()
{
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

Without having to copy-paste four spaces in front of each line I want to indent.

---

The above may seem like a trivial example, but consider this answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6043161/1

Which I then changed (using the code { } button) to:

> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6043161/2

Hoo, boy.

Comment: There is a User Script that implements this functionality here: http://stackapps.com/questions/2440/increase-decrease-indentation-buttons-for-the-editor

Comment: Conversation about dup detection moved to chat: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/415/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-jeff-atwood