# WMD: Code inside lists

Tags: bug, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add increase/decrease tab indent buttons to the editor toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar)

When posting code inside a list you need to indent it by an additional level, i.e. 8 instead of just 4 spaces. The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut and the *Code* button of the editor use the regular 4-space indentation though which is annoying since it requires indenting all the code manually.

Comment: This is a very well-known issue.

Comment: Doesn't make it less annoying :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround:

- Format your code using Ctrl-K:

  ```
  - List item

       Code line 1
       Code line 2
  ```
- Add a dummy character at the very start of the first (formatted) line:

  ```
  - List item

  x     Code line 1
       Code line 2
  ```
- Select all lines of code, hit Ctrl-K again.
- Remove the dummy character:

  ```
  - List item

          Presto!
          And easier than letting the editor guess what you want...
  ```