# Simple copy-pasting a sample code 

Tags: feature-request

Earlier when I wanted to paste several lines of source code or table as the code sample, I used to  manually insert spaces before every line (or paste several spaces to the first of line) to indent it.

Jim proposed a better approach below: First to paste the code, then highlight it and mark it as the code sample.

But isn't it better that if we have already started a code sample area, the site itself supports copy-paste and automatically indents the pasted lines?

Comment: Paste it, highlight it, and click the `{}` button to turn it to code. Or Ctrl+K.

Comment: @Jim :-) Nice trivial idea, thanks!

Comment: In its current form, this requests is dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't think so, I am not talking about increase/decrease *button*, but just *Automatic* indenting the pasted lines while already started a code sample area.