# Add a strike-through to the editing interface

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown

If you highlight some text, you can just press a button to have it automatically emphasized on indented 4 spaces for a code sample. I think it would be great if we had this feature with strike-throughs so I don't have to manually type s tags. People use strikethoughs to delete text from their posts when editing it and adding information. This is nicer than just deleting it because it gets the point across that its older information but you can still see the original text.

Comment: related: [Improvements to editor for formatting source code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/the-editor-possible-improvements)

Comment: I think it is a good idea to have but we'll just have to have the strike tag for now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no way that strikethrough is used enough to justify a button, and I certainly don't want to *encourage* its use any more than it already is..

Comment: Why don't you want to encourage its use?

Comment: Actually I use it a lot. When I ask question I do a multi-teared question in where the answer isn't always done with one post. For that reason, I use the strikethrough because it will make people realize parts of the question is already answered. Like this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079285/how-to-cull-data-from-two-lists-on-two-different-sheets-in-excel-into-a-third-sh

Comment: Strikethrough can be legally useful, when somebody replied to your answer in comments and you fixed your code as a result. If you just fix it, people may start wondering why the comment is odd. This way you show what the original answer was and why the comment is valid.

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer No way! As _user199936_ correctly pointed out, there are far **to many** odd, useless, non-sense comments in entire SE, actually because people are _deleting_ instead of _striking through_. So, I may agree with _Jeff_, that such button isn't welcome, but I certainly won't agree with you, that deleting is better than using strike-through.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, there is more in heaven and earth than is dreamed of in your philosophy. There are a variety of valid uses for the strikethough styling, and you should remain agnostic, not partisan. You don't punish the valid uses because there is the possibility of abuse. Especially so on a site about learning English, where one can strikeout errors and show the corrected version side-by-side. But it's not a big deal, since we have the markup alternatives.

Comment: @trejder Delete those comments, then. Flag as obsolete. A clean, correct answer is more readable than a patchwork of wrong strike through text. And there should not be any need for readers to look at comments at all.

Comment: Sometimes it can be very helpful to see the original mistakes made by the poster, and the **way** of how they eventually got to the answer. This can be more helpful than the actual answer. If you edit and correct everything, this is all gone (and you're not going to look at the history).

Comment: I googled how to strike text and found current topic. I haven't know that I could use del or strike. I vote for adding new button

Comment: Maybe strikethrough isn't used enough because of the missing button. Have you ever edited a post?

Comment: strikethru is super useful to make change announcement dude!

Comment: Strikethrough is not being used much **because** there's no button. Just a minute ago somebody's answer made it clear to me that a part of my question was ridiculous, but if I would just remove that part the answer would look oddly irrelevant to the rest of the question. Thanks to ChrisF's answer I was able to strikethrough.

Comment: Having a strike through button is a useful way of showing that something was true once, but no longer is. By deleting things that are no longer true, you can create confusion to people looking at different sources trying to research a topic. When you strike out old information you confirm it as false; so, that a person looking at your post and another post based on old information can clearly see which information is outdated. So, a strike through can disambiguate confusion caused by change over time.

Comment: @user199936 this makes no sense - an answer should be standalone, and comments should address it, and not the other way around. There is a "flag comment as obsolete" button exactly for that purpose.

Comment: How is this marked as the right answer? The most voted is clearly the right answer. Being a button or not is not the point, the point is to allow people to add strike-though and the most voted answer does just that. Some of you talk about "clean replies", and yet this one is as useless as it could be. I agree this answer doesn't need a strike-through, it needs to be deleted.

Comment: @trejder If removing one comment that should be removed, causes another comment to become nonsense, *generally that one should also just be removed*.

Answer (score 255):

In the absence of a button (and given that Jeff has said it's not likely to be implemented) you can use the HTML tag:

Like <strike>this</strike> or <s>this</s> or <del>this</del>

```
Like <strike>this</strike> or <s>this</s> or <del>this</del>
```

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) for a complete list of the HTML that's allowed.

Comment: One of the key points in the suggestion was that the user didn't have to type one of these.  Providing a button produces a lower barrier of entry for people and promotes the use of the feature -- like bold and italics.  I don't know if strikethrough is the only HTML feature that should be promoted, nor do I have a strong opinion on if strikethrough should be promoted to a button.  Just making an observation that your answer/point seems to go against the grain of the CrazyJugglerDrummer's desire.

Comment: can you do this in comment

Comment: It does <strike>not</strike> work in comments... <s>Even</s> with the alternate <del>tags</del>.

Comment: @Juha HTML S̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ in comments work for me!!!

Comment: C̶h̶e̶a̶t̶e̶r̶.̶

Comment: <strike>this</strike> or <s>this</s> or <del>this</del> Why doesn't it work for me in comments? @JuhaUntinen

Comment: @ChrisF https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/is-there-a-way-to-strike-out-text-in-comments

Comment: is there markdown for this?

Comment: @njzk2 Standard markdown for strikethrough is like ~this~ but I don't think it's supported on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 13):

Might be obvious to some but, as a useful addition, you can wrap your `code` in strikethrough,
e.g. <s>`code...`</s>  *(i.e. `` <s>`code...`</s> ``)*, but it won't show up if you include it inside `` `<s>code</s>` ``.

Handy for code edits...

To use strikethrough within the same code, it is possible to use
`<code>co<s>de...</s></code>` e.g. `code...`.

Comment: I've still yet to see a legitimate use of strike though. It almost universally leads to me reaching for the edit button

Comment: Actually, `<code><s>code</s></code>` will work in questions / answers, but you need to use HTML `<code>` tags instead of backticks (and escape any HTML / Markdown special characters in your code). Of course, it won't work in comments, since those don't support HTML tags at all.

Comment: didn't know <code>. cheers.

Comment: @Ilmari W̶o̶r̶k̶s̶̶ for me!

Comment: @JohnMiliter looks underlined to me...

Comment: @RichardTingle Depends a lot what Stacks you are on.  If you are just on Stackoverflow, you may not see it properly used much, but for English.SE, law.SE, WB.SE, etc. it would be very helpful because it is used in other ways than just preserving simple edits.