# Is there a way to strike out text in comments?

Tags: support, comments

Is there a way to strike out text in comments? The markdown that works for posts does not appear to work in comments.

Comment: n̶o̶ ----------

Comment: w̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶y̶e̶s̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶A̶F̶A̶I̶K̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶a̶ ̶U̶n̶i̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶o̶l̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶[t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶](http://adamvarga.com/strike/)

Comment: <strike>hmmm</strike>  [S̶t̶a̶c̶k̶O̶v̶e̶r̶f̶l̶o̶w̶ ̶E̶d̶i̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶H̶e̶l̶p̶](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Surprisingly, the SO editing guide doesn't say how to use strikeout in comments :(  But @Pekka's tool works.

Comment: @Pekka - You could add that as an answer ;) The only requirement is that the entire answer must use strikeout markup.

Comment: For the love of g-d, why?

Comment: And it doesn't work on at least some mobile browsers by default (Android, cell).

Comment: Related: [Comments should support the strike element](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31228/comments-should-support-the-strike-element)

Comment: @RobertHarvey encase I want to change something I previously stated that had been replied to.

Comment: @Celeritas: Deleting the comment  works quite well in those cases.  The only thing more useless than a useless comment is a useless, struck-out comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but then it's confusing when reading a response to a message that has been delete (or modified).

Comment: @Celeritas Flag the responding comment as obsolete.

Comment: @Pekka On my browser (Firefox on Windows) your comment just appears (badly) underlined.

Comment: Strikeout is useful as it allows you to correct something without changing history and making every one that responded to the now striked out text look like a sucker. @Celeritas you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short, no. As Pekka pointed out, you can use unicode struck-out letters to give the appearance of a `<s>` tag, but you can't use a proper strikeout.  The [SO Editing help that jmort253 linked](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in the comments explicitly enumerates all the markdown you can use:

```
_italic_ and **bold** text,
inline `code in backticks`,
and [basic links](http://example.com).
```

plus a number of shorthand links.

Comment: `*italic*` works for *italic*

Comment: and `__bold__` also works for __bold__. But that's just basic markdown. It's just a shame that SO chose to give us crippled markdown for the comments where they removed some useful features.