# Why does <strike> tag not work in comments?

Tags: support, questions

I tried to explain a correction in someone's comment via a comment, but found that <strike>, <s> and <del> didn't work as it would in the question and answer edit boxes.  Using --strike-- as is apparently done in chat didn't work either.

Why is that?  Is there some alternate way for comments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comments should support the strike element](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31228/comments-should-support-the-strike-element) and [Is there a way to strike out text in comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/is-there-a-way-to-strike-out-text-in-comments)

Comment: Duplicate because relevant :)  Note that several threads contain solutions now.  I even detailed it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63768/does-markdown-have-a-way-to-express-strikeout/318289#318289)