# Why does striking through not work as in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown

In (StackOverflow) chat, when I type

```
---something---
```

It gets struck through.

When I do the same on any SE site, it is not.

What I need to do is the terrible

```
<s>something</s>
```

and then it is <s>struck</s> through. Why does the triple dash not work everywhere? It's much more "Markdown"-y than the html-y `<></>`-stuff.

Comment: Closely related: [Add a strike-through to the editing interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9796) and [Comments should support the strike element](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31228)

Comment: inb4 close voters: this is not a dupe of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/add-a-strike-through-to-the-editing-interface) nor [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9796) question.

Comment: I did not vote to close. I stated these are closely related.

Comment: @rubenvb - er, that's the same question you've linked to twice,

Comment: Strike through support in chat was [introduced as an experimental feature](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/548485#548485), and Balpha is hesitant to add support for it to comments. The feature is not part of the official Markdown spec, and [Jeff Atwood is on record as not wanting to fork the spec](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230014/time-to-fork-markdown), which may or may not be pertinent here.

Comment: @Martijn I didn't mean you ;-), and the other question was indeed the other question you linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Three dashes for strike through is not part of the official Markdown spec. To implement this would require that either the core project is updated or SE fork the project - which [SE are reluctant to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230014/time-to-fork-markdown). I would guess that it's not been done because the benefit gained is not worth the implementation cost.

If you could come up with a compelling reason why the "Markdown-y" method of three dashes is superior to the "HTML-y" `<s></s>` then the team *might* consider it.

The team have probably got more than enough work developing and supporting the sites and Careers, so they aren't going to want to take on more work.

Comment: Not sure when this changed (haven't done the meta reseach) but `---` works now, and `<s>` does not. I'm guessing [balpha's experiment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233928/why-does-striking-through-not-work-as-in-chat#comment769080_233928) stuck. (I found this old question, btw, because I can *never* remember how strike through works in chat. Figured I might as well post an update to this answer while I'm here.)