# Have "Tab" key insert spaces when writing a question or answer

Tags: feature-request, tabs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [The Editor - Possible Improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/the-editor-possible-improvements)
>   [Add increase/decrease tab indent buttons to the editor toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar)

Is it at all possible to have the Tab key insert 4 spaces in the question/answer edit area, instead of moving focus to the next control?

When writing code in questions or answers I could really use such functionality, especially for hierarchically indented code, like this:

```
codecode
codecode 
    codecode
        codecode
        codecode
    codecode
```

What I usually do is copy 4 spaces and then paste them over and over again, but using Tab is more natural (I actually do it by mistake quite often).

I think the usage of Tab for moving focus while editing a question/answer is minimal, and its benefits are insignificant versus the benefits of allowing Tabbed code.

A "neater" feature will be to push not 4 spaces but the differences between the next multiple of 4 and the current amount of spaces in the line (e.g. if I pressed once on space and then Tab, the Tab will insert 3 spaces, like "real" tabulation)

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/the-editor-possible-improvements

Comment: @John: I do think this is a specific feature request that can be accepted or rejected by SO team (and commented on by the community), whereas the question you are referring to is more of a CW request to add ideas to the editor.

Comment: Then take that one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar

Comment: @John: got it. I tried deleting the question but can't since it has an upvoted answer. Will wait for the moderators to do it.

Comment: As much as I'd like this personally, I don't think over-riding the tab key is a good idea because it makes it harder to use the site sans-mouse, which can be a real pain for some users.  The toolbar buttons would help tremendously, though.

Comment: or better yet, DO override the tab button, but make it opt in. click a button that turns "tab lock" on so the user can choose to add the functionality if they wish. i can't believe this has been a known issue since 09 and it's not fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have <kbd>Tab</kbd>  locked in the edit/content window, how will you tab out of it again? Totally breaks the experience of a usable interface.

Can you not just type up your fancy-schmancy code in a plain text editor, making use of its tabbing behaviour and then bring it over?

♨

Comment: I understand your point but disagree it's more important than the editor usability for code input. And I actually use Notepad for most of my code snippets :)

Comment: They already broke expected behaviour with the return key in the comments `textarea`, I'm sure one more infraction wouldn't go amiss - I only say this as a neutral by-stander :)

Comment: So make the Tab work this way only when something is highlighted. When there is no highlight, Tab acts as usual to leave the field forward or backward (with shift).