# Add tab support to indent paragraphs/lines

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have “Tab” key insert spaces when writing a question or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/have-tab-key-insert-spaces-when-writing-a-question-or-answer)

I guess it would be great to include to indent paragraphs or lines when pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button so that we can indent code easily than indenting it with the space bar.

Comment: Tab is an application key, and the browser is the application per se, not the site within it. AFAIK, the behaviour of navigating controls won't go away any time soon - and if you could override it, it may cause more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the tab symbol copied from other text editors (Notepad, forexample).

Also I want to note that you can rise the [holy war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268538/tab-versus-space-indentation-in-c) for choosing [tab or space indentation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/04/death-to-the-space-infidels.html):

> That said, only a moron would use tabs to format their code.
>   * unless you happen to be programming in whitespace or Python

For this site standard is a space indentation, and I don't think this gonna change sometimes.