# Is there any chance of adding "tab character" available in the editing textbox?

Tags: feature-request, edits, markdown, code-formatting, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have “Tab” key insert spaces when writing a question or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/have-tab-key-insert-spaces-when-writing-a-question-or-answer)

When I'm writing PHP code as an answer/question on Stack Overflow, I am trying to beautify my code with formatting,

```
function aboutMe(){
    //make four spaces
    //another four spaces
    //and another spaces
}
```

On this code, I had to press space 12 times instead of 3 times with tab.

For those who still didn't get me but know jQuery:

```
$('#wmd-input').bind('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // make four spaces
  } 
});
```

This feature would

- prevent us from switching between the edit textearea and the Tags text input and
- allow us to make applications/PHP code faster even in a simple textbox.

Comment: The problem is that now one needs a mouse or some other unknown key combination to hop to the next input line (tags, edit comments, or *Post answer* button).

Comment: I never switch to tabs input with TAB. It could be as profile pref feature :)

Comment: @random: There were no questions solved before me, that is what I asked it. Somebody should accept/reject this feature