# Interpret tabs as 8 spaces at the line-beginning in code blocks

Tags: feature-request, markdown

This is related but different to

[Auto-expand TAB character in code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146114/auto-expand-tab-character-in-code-formatting)

I have seen it several times: beginners' questions like [How to loop through a set (not a list) of rules in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863352/how-to-loop-through-a-set-not-a-list-of-rules-in-prolog)

It would help a lot if tabs at the beginning of a line would be interpreted as 8 spaces. That is, four spaces for the block and four spaces inside such that some indentation is visible. Currently the only way to fix it is to do a manual edit.

Comment: Begin the religious war on tabs vs. spaces in 3..2..1..

Comment: For that matter, begin the 2, 3, 4 or 8 war. BTW-8 is extremely silly for programing purposes.

Comment: @dmckee: I do not care how much the actual indentation actually is, what is the problem here is that no indentation is shown at all in this case.

Comment: @false then wouldn't that be a bug?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: The situation is almost always: SO-newbies pasting  in a program. Looking at in the textarea, looks good; post. Then this code comes up completely unreadable.

Comment: Isn't this a problem of the code example being indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces? This of course doesn't solve the problem, but I think that solving it does not lie in deviating from the markdown specification.