# Can we get a toggle button in the post editor that lets us use the Tab key to insert 4 Spaces?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor

Could we get a Toggle Button when writing a post that would make it so that the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key inserts <kbd>Space x 4</kbd> instead of tabbing out of the `TextBox`?

There are so many times when I'm writing an answer containing code and would like to indent it correctly, however the tab key leaves the `TextBox` instead of indenting my typing.

This is even more annoying when writing answers, as the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key moves to the "Post Answer" button, and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> before you notice ends up posting an incomplete answer.

My current workaround is to copy 4 spaces and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent my code as I'm typing it, but this is obnoxious as it requires an extra step, and has to be re-copied anytime I copy/paste anything else. And I'm very forgetful and frequently hit Tab out of habit anyways.

Note that this is not quite a duplicate of [Have “Tab” key insert spaces when writing a question or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20156/158605) as I'm not asking for a universal feature that would prevent keyboard navigation completely, but would instead like an optional toggle button or CheckBox to turn this feature on/off depending on user preference :)

Comment: I actually do think it's a duplicate, it could be suggested as an answer to that question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can't actually post this as an answer to the linked question since it is closed as a duplicate to two other questions, one of which is quite a bit broader than this one, and the other which is asking for something different (indent/outdent buttons on the editor) :) I think this feature request is much more specific to this case only, and should not be closed as a duplicate to that one.

Comment: Yick, it is indeed closed. We could re-open it, perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd still prefer my feature request of adding a toggle button to turn this feature on/off instead of reopening an old question asking for this as a universal feature, and posting the Toggle suggestion as an answer, which may or may not get noticed by the SE team that implements feature requests.

Comment: And have Shift + tab remove 4 spaces

Comment: I'm such a dork... but having the tab key not - ***insert a tab*** -, or spaces, or whatever.. is literally one of the most excruciating things in my life...  I do it so often when posting, I almost give up out of hysteric frustration...  It is definitely some _space-loving_ space vs. tabs nazi over at SE that insists on this absolutely stupid behavior.  I've used PLENTY of forms / online IDE's that allow you to use the tab as god intended... to insert 4 spaces!

Comment: Related: [Should Shift + Spacebar create a tab indent in Se?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234662/should-shift-spacebar-create-a-tab-indent-in-se)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to write the code in your editor/IDE of choice - effectively offline and then copy+paste it into the answer box. This works for the following reasons:

1. You can actually check the code compiles and runs before posting it as an answer.
2. The editor/IDE will do all the code formatting for you - virtually all languages use 4 spaces these days.
3. If the formatting isn't 100% correct a quick click of the code button should sort it out.

Comment: I often don't have an IDE or editor open when I answer SO questions :)

Comment: @Rachel: So open Notepad (or any other text editor). :-)

Comment: @KenWhite What you want me to do extra work??? You're crazy... moving mice is hard :)

Answer (score 1):

They should just add indent/dedent buttons like good editors have, so you can just select and hit the button to move in either direction.

Comment: I'm not against this idea, but I wonder how many people would then think they could indent paragraphs without applying the formatting as code. (Or: be wondered why indented text is formatted as code.) For other readers, see [Add increase/decrease tab indent buttons to the editor toolbar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

This might make the site harder to use for some people with disabilities ***and*** breaks the usability. I understand what you're saying with the whole "tab lock" thing, but that's another level of complexity in both the code and the UI. Suggestion: have <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> = <kbd>Space x4</kbd>. To prevent the issue about accidentally posting, maybe go to the 'community wiki' checkbox first? Not the best, but...

Also, one thing I do is type the code out in the editor (ignoring the preview) and then just select all the text and hit the code button. It works fine, and you forget about it.

Comment: Tab *followed* by Space? I wonder how one would implement that without breaking the regular use of the Tab key.

Comment: @Arjan you're right, the other way would be better. Repeated don't show, so it's just the code that uses repeated spaces, thus probably no one holds down the space bar.

Comment: That's not a good key combo because it doesn't work lol. **Try holding space in the editor:** You've just created a space. **Try holding tab:** you've just exited the editor. Neither of those behaviors can be removed without breaking something very important (regular spaces and tab order). [This combination does the trick though.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234662/should-shift-spacebar-create-a-tab-indent-in-se)