# Tab indention in questions/answers

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change 'TAB' keyboard press functionality when typing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93346/change-tab-keyboard-press-functionality-when-typing-a-question)

When writing code, it is common practice for many text editors to allow the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to be used as an indention key. Either by literally adding tabs or by adding 4 spaces. I've seen it done in several websites as well ([www.jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/), for instance), and I think it could really be useful here.