# Let the user choose what the TAB does in the editor with caveats

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editor, tab-key

I've read in the meta the [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/the-editor-possible-improvements) on why it's not a good idea to [Change 'TAB' keyboard press functionality when typing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93346/change-tab-keyboard-press-functionality-when-typing-a-question) so that it insert spaces instead of changing focus. The main concern is not to change the way textarea's have worked for a long time.

I totally agree with that, just like i think that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> should bring you to a new line inside a textarea, but facebook, for example, gives you an opportunity to override this default behaviour if you feel that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> should send the message instead. So why don't do something like this withe the <kbd>Tab</kbd>? 
We could have an option just like in facebook which

- appears only to registered users (no need to confuse casual users, a textarea is a textarea and should behave in a standard way)
- is disabled by default (the standard way behaviour is preserved)
- if is checked, it insert a tab instead of moving focus

Do you still think that this would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a user script for this: [Better handling of indentation and the TAB key when editing posts](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts)

As is the usual answer to "make it a user setting": We're very careful about preferences, because anything that most people don't use should usually not complicate the UI. User scripts have somewhat established themselves as an alternative for this; in addition, they're a good way to solicit feedback on the usefulness of a feature. It wouldn't be unprecedented for user script functionality (created by us or others) to eventually turn into core functionality.

Comment: While I love the script, please don't mess with the default browser tab navigation functionality unless users _explicitly_ request it (eg. by installing a script). Messing with accessibility is a _bad thing_.

Comment: @cdeszaq Absolutely agreed. The tab key will never by default do anything other than what the user expects from a browser.

Comment: @balpha this is a perfect way to accomodate the needs of the users! :)