# Let users tab inside of question/answer box

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Editor - Possible Improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/the-editor-possible-improvements)
>   [Have “Tab” key insert spaces when writing a question or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/have-tab-key-insert-spaces-when-writing-a-question-or-answer)
>   [Let the user choose what the TAB does in the editor with caveats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122529/let-the-user-choose-what-the-tab-does-in-the-editor-with-caveats)

I frequently want to use Tab to indent my questions, for example to indent a snippet for code formatting.  Currently, tab just moves me to the "Tags" input.  I think most people would benefit more from being able to tag inside the question or answer box.

Here is how such a feature could be implemented:  http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/viewA94BBC8A-8DC4-4F14-98F9-DEDFCF40DA07.htm

I realize this is a trade-off between easy switching between elements and editing, but personally I would benefit a lot from the faster editing this would enable.

Comment: I like this idea.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97152, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/have-tab-key-insert-spaces-when-writing-a-question-or-answer

Comment: See also [Increase/Decrease Indentation Buttons for the Editor](http://stackapps.com/questions/2440)

Comment: I suppose this is a duplicate of previous discussions, at least to the extent that those talk about tabbing rather than tab buttons.   But is there a way to get some admin feedback?  Not sure what the process is

Comment: You already did that by putting the [feature-request] tag on your question.