# Why "Tab", "PageUp" and "PageDown" aren't working on text area?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let the user choose what the TAB does in the editor with caveats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122529/let-the-user-choose-what-the-tab-does-in-the-editor-with-caveats)

I was wondering Why "Tab", "PageUp" and "PageDown" aren't working on text area?
it can be very useful when you want to edit or scrolling up/down the code you are going to post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would break user expectations of what those keys do...since they have the same behavior on 99.99999% of the internet, we follow that well established convention.  More accurately, we don't *interfere* with that convention, we let normal browser behavior happen.

If you want that behavior and wish to deviate from conventions we have no objections, just install or write a User Script to do so in *your* browser(s)...but changing the behavior for *all* users is not something we'd want to do.

Comment: Tab should not be captured for accessibility reasons - keyboard users won't be able to tab out of textareas if you do that. Also, balpha wrote a very good userscript to handle tabs in textareas for those who want it to indent text: http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts